# Debugging PHPSpreadsheet blank screen

Tags: php, phpspreadsheet

I'm replacing PHPExcel with PHPSpreadheet and it works OK in test script, but shows blank screen when used in my app (). In PHP settings, I have display_errors enabled, but I get blank screen (and empty log) nevertheless.

Specifically, just constructing the class throws a blank page:

```
(...)
die ('here');
$spreadsheet = new Spreadsheet();
(...)
```

Displays "here".

```
(...)
$spreadsheet = new Spreadsheet();
die ('here 2');
(...)
```

Shows blank screen.

Any ideas on how to debug it? Thanks!

Comment: i think we need more code.

Comment: I've figured it out - despite I *do* have error_reporting = E_ALL & ~E_DEPRECATED & ~E_STRICT, it didn't show fatal error due to require_once problem (autoloader loading from wrong dir). Changed that to error_reporting = E_ALL and can finally see the error instead of blank screen. Funny enough, it didn't even log it! It's php 7.3.19-1+ubuntu18.04.1+deb.sury.org+1

Comment: So you resolve it?

Comment: Yeah thanks... I'll answer so I can mark it as resolved

Answer (score 0):

I've figured it out - despite I do have

```
error_reporting = E_ALL & ~E_DEPRECATED & ~E_STRICT
```

it didn't show fatal error due to require_once problem (autoloader loading from wrong dir).
Changed that to

```
error_reporting = E_ALL
```

and can finally see errors instead of blank screen - and resolve them.

It didn't even log it! It's php 7.3.19-1+ubuntu18.04.1+deb.sury.org+1